# Solace JCSMP API shows "Subscriber flow congested"

Tags: solace

I received the following when using Solace JCSMP Java library subscribing to topics under heavy load with Direct Messaging.  May I know what is the impact? Will this cause message loss and what is the remedy?

```
2018-10-08 10:18:43 INFO  FlowHandleImpl:67 - Subscriber flow congested, disabling connection read.
2018-10-08 10:18:43 INFO  FlowHandleImpl:42 - Subscriber flow uncongested, re-enabling connection read.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Solace Support, this is caused by the internal message flow queue in the API being full.  The following summarizes what I understand from Solace Support.

The Java API maintains an internal queue of messages for delivery to the consumer session. If this queue reaches a consumer's congestion limit (default is 5000 elements), the API stops reading from the socket and the egress buffer work queues are back pressured on the Solace router. The "Subscriber flow congested, disabling connection read"
log is generated when this occurs. This can result in message discards.  Once the application catches up the API resumes reading from the socket and generates a log like "Subscriber flow uncongested, re-enabling connection read".

We can tune this by calling [setConsumerDefaultFlowCongestionLimit()](https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/java/com/solacesystems/jcsmp/JCSMPGlobalProperties.html#setConsumerDefaultFlowCongestionLimit(int)) of com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPGlobalProperties

The following CLI commands can be used to check for message discards when this issue happens:

```
show client <name> stats detail
show client <name> connections wide
show client <name> stats queues
```

If the messages are published with Deliver-To-One (DTO) set to true, then increasing the number of message subscribers will help to load balance the load and the issue of message discards could be alleviated.

It is also interesting to know how Solace API handles incoming messages with the [Threading When Receiving Messages](https://docs.solace.com/Solace-PubSub-Messaging-APIs/Developer-Guide/Threading-When-Receiving.htm) in order to understand this issue.

In both synchronous and asynchronous receiving of messages, each consumer flow has it’s own internal message queue. Messages are always added on to these queues by the context/reactor thread.

In the asynchronous case, when a message is added to a consumer flow’s message queue, there is an event added to a separate queue called the consumer notification dispatch queue. The event wakes up the consumer dispatch thread.  Based on the event, the dispatch thread will dequeue the message from the message queue and deliver it to the corresponding message callback.

In the synchronous case, the application threads dequeue messages from the message queues by calling receive(). The consumer notification dispatch queue is not used in this case.